# MySQL Full Text Search Custom Sort Logic

Tags: java, mysql, full-text-search

If I search like AGAINST ('word1 word2 word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE) how can I have the results to be sorted based on number of unique words found in row?

For example: ( expected result )

1. row1 - all words
2. row2 - word1 and word2
3. row3 - word1 and word3
4. row4 - word3

... etc